# SQL OPEN MASTER KEY with variable not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm trying to parametize the use of a SQL Server master key. I don't want to hardcode the password. Is there a way to call the following with a variable? Pretty sure I'm missing something.

```
DECLARE @Password NVARCHAR(50) = 'super-secure-password'

-- Open master key for use
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = @Password
```

> Incorrect syntax near @Password. Expecting STRING or TEX_LEX

This works if I just hardcode it like so:

```
-- Open master key for use
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'super-secure-password'
```

I have also tried some variations on this but to no avail, I just get a

> Incorrect syntax near 'super-secure-password'

, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @Password NVARCHAR(50)
SELECT @Password = 'super-secure-password'
SELECT @TSQL = 'OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ' + @Password
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Comment: You can't parametrise the value of `PASSWORD` no; as the error tells you is *must* be a literal. As for why the dynamic statement fails, that's because the statement would be `OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = GXM8RPDELrFM5bX02Cnj`; notice the password isn't wrapped in single quotes. As, however, the dynamic statement is in a separate lower scope, and unless my memory serves me incorrectly, the outer scope would not have the key "opened", and the key would be "closed" in the inner scope as soon as it completes.

Comment: Also, I hope that isn't your real master key password. If it is, it's now compromised and you should change it.

Comment: Thanks, ja that is not my real master key password :) 
You're right, a silly mistake I just solved it - the wrong number of enclosing quotes

Comment: Note that, if you *are* injecting the password, I recommend using `QUOTENAME` (or `REPLACE` if the password *could* be over 128 characters) to inject it. As good practice you should be using `sys.sp_executesql` as well. You can't parametrise statements like `EXEC (@TSQL)` and that results in bad habits such as injecting values that should be parametrised.

Comment: Thanks, will look into that

Comment: It helps to realise the T-SQL is a crufty language with poor orthogonality. In many languages you're probably familiar with, most places where you need to supply a string you can supply a constant/literal, a variable or an expression. Not so in T-SQL. If you get an error like this, you need to check the documentation and specifically the syntax. If it doesn't explicitly show a variable or an expression being allowed, but only a literal, then that's all that's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to comments and feedback from @Larnu & @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is the solution I went with for now.

```
DECLARE @TSQL_OpenKey NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Password NVARCHAR(128)
SET @Password = 'not-my-real-password'
SET @TSQL_OpenKey = 'OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''' + @Password + ''''
EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @TSQL_OpenKey, N'@Password NVARCHAR(128)', @Password = @Password
```

The line in question really, is this, where I was simply missing string quotes.

```
SET @TSQL_OpenKey = 'OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''' + @Password + ''''
```

I also tried to implement @Larnu's suggestion to use `sp_executesql` rather than `EXEC`. Will still look at `QUOTENAME` etc.

This will eventually be wrapped into a sproc where `@Password` would be provided externally.